# Can I install windows onto a new SSD while retaining programs on the existing HDD?

Tags: windows, installation, ssd, transfer

I currently have a 2TB HDD (About 1.3TB full,) and want to buy a new SSD to use as a boot device and for a few programs.

Is it possible for me to install windows onto the ssd, transfer settings and a few programs, uninstall from the hdd and keep other existing programs on the hdd? The only methods I've seen for changing boot device require a full transfer. Something I can't do due to the size of existing content. I also have no other media to transfer programs onto.

Comment: Just change the boot order of the devices.  You can do that within the BIOS or UEFI settings which ever is applicable to your machine.

Comment: Depends on how much work you are willing to do to transfer the settings and programs. Options that come to mind are using Windows easy transfer, creating ntfs links between the drives and blindly copying the windows installation to the ssd.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure what you think that'll solve. I need to move the windows install to the SSD while retaining programs on the HDD, changing the boot order won't do anything.

Comment: You indicated you wanted to install Windows, and transfer your personal files and program settings to the new installation, changing the order is the first step.  Microsoft offers a free copy of a third-party program to transfer program settings.

Comment: Transferring your actual installed programs is not possible ( due to the limitations you given us ), but you can transfer their settings, easy enough.

Comment: @Paul Just transferring the windows install blindly/via windows easy transfer will break program installs won't it? I would like to avoid creating symlinks if I can.

Comment: @Ramhound Not I did not indicate I wanted to transfer files and programs to the new install, that's precisely what I'm NOT trying to do. I want the windows install on the SSD and the existing programs to remain on the HDD. Saying it's not possible isn't helpful (While it may be true.) If you don't have a solution to my problem don't comment giving me things that won't work in my situation.

Answer (score -1):

Samsung have a software call Samsung magician. It is very easy to use and transfers data and OP. I should also mention that the drives must be same size.

Another software you can try is called partition wizard  (freeware) allows you to create a 'clone' of your existing drive. http://www.partitionwizard.com/

Comment: This does not directly answer the question. You stated two pieces of software (and OP has not indicated that his HDD capacity equals that of his SSD), so how can he use that software to transfer just Windows and not his programs?

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem as the SSD is smaller than the HDD and I have already said I can't & don't want to blind copy.